# Webkit: Resize div and elements within div, according to window size

Tags: javascript, webkit, webkit-transform

I have `div` element that contains text which I am trying to resize while scaling the interior text with it.

The `webkit-transform: scale( blah, blah )` CSS property is great for scaling the div by  specific factor, but I need it to scale **proportional to the window size**.

Anyone know any ways to do this?

Comment: I think you will have to get the window-size (with jquery: $(window).width()... ) and the adjust the css also through jquery: $('#yourDiv').css('-webkit-transform','scale('+size+','+size+')');

Comment: Ah I feared as much. Will post a working version as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

You can use percents? And make a proportion if you need to.